# How to get radio buttons to work within document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, audio

The html code in the "document.getElementById" section will work when it is stand along, but although it produces the radio buttons when nested inside "document.getElementById" the buttons don't work. I wonder if its to do with nesting the "document.getElementById"

```
     <span id="Item1"></span>

     <script>

     document.getElementById("Item1").innerHTML = '<center><table bgcolor="#ddceff" width="550" border="2"><TR><TD><center>TEST<BR><audio id="player" src="https://media.radiodgh.com:8443/stream"></audio><div><button onclick="document.getElementById("player").play()">Play</button><button onclick="document.getElementById("player").pause()">Pause</button><button onclick="document.getElementById("player").volume += 0.1">Vol +</button><button onclick="document.getElementById("player").volume -= 0.1">Vol -</button></div></center></font></center></TD></TR></TABLE>'

     </script>
```

Comment: what is your goal here?

Comment: This is a just part of the overall code I am using. I use the getElementById to operate when certain conditions are met. When it does, it should display radio buttons to allow the listener to listen to a radio stream.

Comment: Surely you can use CSS to hide the radio buttons then when a conditions is met, get the element by id and set its style to visible.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the backslash ( \ ) escape character to prevent JavaScript from interpreting a quote as the end of the string. Hence the references to ('player') have to be ([backslash]'player[backslash]').